# Find and get traceback for unknown large RAM allocation in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, memory-profiling

There are a lot of question on here about profiling Python memory usage in specific functions, or monitoring overall process RAM usage, or getting RAM usage breakdowns at specific manually instrumented places in a program. But none of this helps me at all. What I need to do is *find* which part of my code is causing a large RAM allocation.

For context, I am doing some work with TensorFlow 2, and at a certain point I get this warning:

```
Allocation of 10000000000 exceeds 10% of system memory.
```

Ok, great, I should look into that, I probably accidentally triggered some enormous broadcast or something. But where the heck did that happen? I have no idea. I thought there would be a simple way to profile my code and find out where the largest RAM allocation occurred, and what the call stack at that point was, but so far I have not found any way to do it amongst the zillions of Python memory tools that I looked through. Any ideas? Did I miss something obvious?